# What Objective C type is a callback passed to Swift UI as a React Native prop?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to pass a callback as a prop from React Native to a custom Swift component but whenever I call the function from Swift, the app crashes with the error:

```
No +[RCTConvert RCTResponseSenderBlock:] function found.

-[RCTComponentData createPropBlock:isShadowView:]
    RCTComponentData.m:258
-[RCTComponentData propBlockForKey:isShadowView:]
__37-[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:]_block_invoke
__NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
-[RCTComponentData setProps:forView:]
__50-[RCTUIManager createView:viewName:rootTag:props:]_block_invoke.423
__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke
__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke.489
__RCTExecuteOnMainQueue_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
```

Here is my Objective C declaration file:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(AppleNativeWebViewManager, RCTViewManager)

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(urlToLoad, NSString)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(matchedUrlCallback, RCTResponseSenderBlock)

@end
```

It seems like `RCTResponseSenderBlock` is the wrong type, even though it works when creating a native module, not a native view.

What type should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this type:

`RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onSuccessfulAuthentication, RCTBubblingEventBlock)`

Important note: the name of the prop must start with `on` for the callback to be fired. If it doesn't, the function can't be called.